# I upgraded my angular version from 13 to 14 .. getting generic type error TS2707 for ng-circle-progress

Tags: migration

I upgraded my angular version from 13 to 14.. migration is completed , but on running application with ng serve its giving error for ng-circle-progress module .
Error: node-modules/ng-circle-progress/lib/ng-circle-progress-component.d.ts:- error TS2707 :
Generic Type 'ComponentDeclaration requires between 7 and 8 arguments.

tried solving by using npm install @angular/ng-circle-progress --force --legacy-peer-deps but nothing worked. Can anyone provide solution to this. Any lead will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue that I was facing was occurring as some npm packages were upgraded to 15 as its latest. Though I am migrating to 14 not 15.
So to solve that I checked all packages version relevant to version 14 from npm official site
for eg : for @angular/animations

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/animations

Similarly check versions for each package upgraded to 15 and change in package.json
and finally run 'npm install --legacy-peer-deps'
You will be good to go .
If you still face issues, restart application and do ng serve.